# How to add event handler in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, mouseevent

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_to" runat="server" CssClass="txt_box" Enabled="true">
 </asp:TextBox>
 <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
      TargetControlID="txt_to" MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="10"
      CompletionSetCount="3" EnableCaching="true" FirstRowSelected="true"
      UseContextKey="True" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
      DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
      ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" />
```

I have the `txt_to` text box which has auto complete extender, when the some email id is suggested by the auto complete the user selects the suggestion with the mouse or clicks enter, How to add a event handler so that a `;` is inserted at the end of email id. so that the user can start typing for next email id without entering the `;`

Comment: is AutoCompleteExtender the one in ajax control toolkit ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript below:

```
function pageLoad() {
     var extender = $find("AutoCompleteEx"); // extender BehaviorID

     var original = Function.createDelegate(extender, extender._getTextWithInsertedWord);
     extender._getTextWithInsertedWord = function (wordToInsert) {
          var text = original(wordToInsert);
          return text + ';';
     }
}
```